# How to limit sklearn GridSearchCV cpu usage?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, parallel-processing, joblib

I use `GridSearchCV` as follows:

```
gsearch_lgb = GridSearchCV(
    model(**self.model_params),
    param_grid=self.model_params,
    n_jobs=2,
    verbose=99,
    scoring=self.cv_scoring,
    cv=4,
)
```

But joblib still uses my all cores:

[image]

I also tried `n_jobs=-19` since sklearn document said
"For n_jobs below -1, (n_cpus + 1 + n_jobs) are used"

But still not working, all my cpus are used.

How should I modified my code to reduce CPU usage?

Comment: Does your model run in parallel if invoked without GridSearchCV?

Comment: Is your model running in parallel due to BLAS parallelism? I recommend using [threadpoolctl](https://github.com/joblib/threadpoolctl) to control this.

Comment: Minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I have to set `n_jobs` as [lgbm.Regressor](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMRegressor.html) parameter also, so the total CPU usage would be:

`total_cpu` = `GridSeaechCV.fit n_jobs` x `lgbm.fit n_jobs`